# JQuery: Toggle multiple text in click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a JQuery function that toggles a column in the database (as per datatables.net)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide([1]);" id="name">Show Name</a>
```

clicking on `Show Name` will hide the column but I also want to change the link now to `Hide Name`.

**There are multiple links to hide/show columns such as Show Address, Show Company etc and they all goto the same fnShowHide function.**

JQuery toggle does not work embedded inside a click. `(this).text` does not work either. a seperate toggle function outside of fnShowHide sets the link to `display:none`

```
function fnShowHide( iCol )
        {
```

Comment: Is the link with 'Show name' inside the column you want to show/hide?

Comment: no its not its just a link above the table that toggles columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

#### Markup

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide.call(this, [1]);" id="name">Show Name</a>
```

#### JS

```
function fnShowHide( iCol ) {
 //Your code
    $(this).text(function(_, text) { //now this refers to the element clicked
        return text === 'Show Name' ? 'Hide Name' : 'Show Name';
   });
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6fyK/)**

or use jquery for event registration and get rid of inline onclick attribute on the element, use data-* attribute to specify the relative data for the element and use jquery data api to get it :

#### Makup

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-icol="[1]" id="name">Show Name</a>
```

#### JS

```
$(function(){
     $('#name').click(fnShowHide);
});

function fnShowHide()
{
     var iCol = $(this).data('icol'); //will give [1]
         //Your code
     $(this).text(function(_, text) { //now this refers to the element clicked
        return text === 'Show Name' ? 'Hide Name' : 'Show Name';
     });
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PQLPp/)**

**Update**

Based on the comment support for multiple fields.

```
$(function () {
    $('.fields').click(fnShowHide);
});

var showregex = /^Show/i; //matches starting Show word
var hideregex = /^Hide/i; //matches starting Hide word

function fnShowHide() {

    var iCol = $(this).data('icol'); //will give [1]
    console.log(iCol);
    //Your code
    $(this).text(function (_, text) { //now this refers to the element clicked

    return showregex.test(text) ? //test if it Show
                 text.replace(showregex, 'Hide') : //replace it with hide
                 text.replace(hideregex, 'Show'); // else replace it with show

    });
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sx4ht/)**

Comment: as in the question there will be multiple links (show Name, Show Address)for the same function (fnShowHide) so the first answer wont work

Comment: @Jabda Can you place the strings in data-attribute? if so we can still make it work well...

Comment: or i have another solution detecting the Show or Hide words.

Comment: which ever is simpler, I am trying to avoid having a showhide function for each link

Comment: Cool then... here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/x2Ymt/

Comment: i have just provided a common class names for them for a better selector, if you dont want just specify them comma separated.

Comment: brilliant Thank you did not occur to me to use regex and was not aware of data-var

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `text` method to show the required text

```
function fnShowHide( iCol ) {

    $(this).text(function(i, txt) {
        return txt === 'Show Name' ? 'Hide Name' : 'Show Name';
   });
}
```

Also it is a better idea to remove `inline` events and assign them in the javascript files instead..

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="[1]" id="name">Show Name</a>
```

And use **data-*** attributes to hold the number if any..

**Javascript**

```
$('a').on('click', fnShowHide);

function fnShowHide() {
    var $this = $(this);
        iCol = $this.data('id');
    $this.text(function (i, txt) {
        return txt === 'Show Name' ? 'Hide Name' : 'Show Name';
    });
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6fyK/1/)**